# Listening to text/event-stream using RestSharp

Tags: c#, restsharp, server-sent-events

I'm currently doing this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    string tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
    Console.Write(tempFile);
    var client = new RestClient(BaseURL);
    using (var writer = File.OpenWrite(tempFile)) {
        var req = new RestRequest {
            ResponseWriter = (responseStream) => {
                using (responseStream) {
                    responseStream.CopyTo(writer);
                }
            }
        };
        var response = client.DownloadData(req);
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

And, it saves data to the specified Temp file. However, when another event is supposed to be sent; the file isn't updated. This is understandable when I read the code; but I have no idea what else to do to make it listen and not just download it once and save it to a file once.

Comment: What event are you expecting for the file to be updated.

Comment: @Prany Everytime a change in the database happens, an event is sent.

Comment: Is it possible to add database schema in the question ?

Comment: @Prany It's Firebae; just plain JSON.

Comment: can you add the schema of it in question

Comment: @Prany I'd have to filter out a lot of stuff, is there any reason why you need the data? It's just JSON.

Comment: I asked the schema thinking if there is any column value which updates after each event. If that the case you can write a recursive method to see the change